# MySQL using only first 20 characters of a string when ordering records

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

It appears that when I’m using `order by name` statement where `name` has a `varchar(255)` type, MySQL at my server doesn’t place records in proper order if they have same 20 first characters of `name` field. It seems like MySQL doesn’t care about 21st character at all: it actually preserves the same incorrect order when sorting in descending order.

I replicated my table on another MySQL installation and everything is OK there. But what do I do about this limitation on a server? I can’t reinstall MySQL there because I’m using shared hosting.

**Update**: the `name` field doesn’t belong to any index and creating index on this field doesn’t help either.

MySQL version is 5.1.55, engine is MyISAM.

**Update 2**: I originally used `cp1251_general_ci` collation but then I tried other collations and got the exact same result. For strings I used `'123456789012345678901'/'123456789012345678902'` and `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstauvwxyz'/'abcdefghijklmnopqrstbuvwxyz'`, same result.

Ordering seems to not take into consideration all characters starting from the 21st, but otherwise it’s working as it should.

Interestingly, when using `ORDER BY substring(name, 2)` the 21st character matters but the 22nd does not.

Comment: it's not a good idea to repeated string prefix stored in a table, you souldn't store them in the first place!

Comment: table engine? mysql version?, in MyISAM or innodb(mysql -v 6, I think), you can create text index, probably that would help you.  Make a copy of the table first before testing.

Comment: Is there an index on _name_? MySQL will use indexes to satisfy _ORDER BY_ s and if you have a partial index on it then that may be the issue or part of it.

Comment: The 'name' field doesn’t belong to any index and unfortunately creating index on this field doesn’t help either.

Comment: MySQL version is 5.1.55, engine is MyISAM.

Comment: what character set and collation are you using? Can you show an example of the strings being ordered incorrectly?

Comment: Do some of your records not start with the same 20 characters, and are those records being sorted correctly? If not, try creating some records like that so you can test whether ORDER BY is doing anything at all.

Comment: I originally used cp1251_general_ci collation but then I tried other collations and got the exact same result. For strings I used '123456789012345678901'/'123456789012345678902' and 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstauvwxyz'/'abcdefghijklmnopqrstbuvwxyz', same result. Ordering seems to not take into consideration all characters starting from the 21st, but otherwise it’s working as it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

could you check your max_length_for_sort_data  and max_sort_length variables? default is 1024, if you have one of those set to 20 then that explains it all.

```
mysqladmin -u root -p variables | grep sort
Enter password: 
| max_length_for_sort_data                | 1024                                                                                      |
| max_sort_length                         | 1024                                                                                      |
| myisam_max_sort_file_size               | 2146435072                                                                                |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size                 | 8388608                                                                                   |
| optimizer_switch                        | index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on |
| sort_buffer_size                        | 2097144                                                                                   |
```

You can find more info [ORDER BY optimisation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/order-by-optimization.html) chapter of the mysql server manual and at the [max_length_sort_data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_length_for_sort_data) definition.

Comment: Exactly, max_sort_length variable is set to 20. Thank you!